# Potential problems when we are migrating from Installshield to WIX 4

Tags: windows, wix, installshield

we have a legacy installer built using Installshield. Considering the cost and licensing issues we are moving towards Wix. If any has made this switch what were the problems you faced like Upgrade scenarios ?

Comment: It all depends how complex your Installshield package is. Wix is somethat fiddly and involved, but you can get a great start using the Wix toolkit's **dark.exe** to decompile your Installshield MSI and view the resulting Wix markup. I usually remove all user interface elements and link with a standard Wix template such as mondo and then work to fix custom actions.

Answer (score 0):

I did this migration two years ago for the same reason and it was not as easy as I thought. The biggest problems I faced were:

1. Migrate the InstallScript to C# custom actions.
2. Complex upgrade definitions in InstallShield.
3. Binaries were automatically added to the InstallShield package, we wanted to switch to manual when using WiX, for better control. Later we reverted to automatic harvest using heat.
4. Rewrite the user interface. We had a very customized user interface in InstallShield and the conversion to WiX UI proved to be a real pain.

Today, I would do the following:

1. Migrate...
2. Use simple upgrade in WiX. Block downgrades, allow automatic upgrades.
3. Use heat harvesting with project references.
4. Use the standard user interface provided by WiXUIExtension.

But after all the migration proved to be beneficial to my project.